# What is the distribution of gaps?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, sampling

Randomly select $n$ numbers from the universe $\{1,2\dots,m\}$ with or without replacement, and sort the numbers in ascending order.

We can get a list of number $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$, and then we can get the difference between two consecutive numbers and get the gap list:
$\{a_1, a_2-a_1,\dots ,a_n-a_{n-1}\}$

So my question is: what is the distribution of the gaps.

Let $A_i$ be the number of gaps which are equal to $i$, what is the distribution of $A_i$?

Update: I clarify that there should two situation to consider: with or without replacement.

Comment: I suspect the answer will be complicated. It's much simpler in the continuous case, which is treated [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25295/simulating-uniformly-on-s1-x-in-mathbbrn-mid-x-1-1). The paper Mariano linked to says something about the relationship to the discrete case. (I'm assuming that by "randomly select" you mean "independently select with uniform distribution".)

Comment: @joriki: An inclusion-exclusion approach seems to produce something worthwhile.

Comment: @David: Worthwhile, but complicated :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An inclusion-exclusion argument gives us the following for the distributions of the $A_i$.

We first consider the case of the $n$ numbers being distinct (selection **without replacement**).

If $1\leqslant n \leqslant m$, $1\leqslant i \leqslant m+1-n$ and $0\leqslant k \leqslant M_i$, then we have:

$$
\textrm{P}(A_i=k)\ =\ P\:(m,n,i,k)\ =\ \frac{1}{T}\: \sum_{j=k}^{M_i} (-1)^{j-k} {j\choose k} {n\choose j} {m-ij\choose n-j}
$$

where $T={m\choose n}$ is the total number of configurations, and $M_i=\textrm{min}(n,\lfloor\frac{m-n}{i-1}\rfloor)$ is the maximum possible gap size.

$Q_k={n\choose k} {m-ik\choose n-k}$ is a count of the combinations with *at least* $k$ gaps of size $i$, determined by first choosing $k$ gaps of size $i$ and then arbitrarily choosing how the remaining 'space' is split up. However $Q_k$ counts combinations with *more than* $k$ $i$-gaps multiple times; indeed combinations with $j$ $i$-gaps are counted $j \choose k$ times. Thus if $R_k$ is the number of combinations with *exactly* $k$ gaps of size $i$, we have $R_k=Q_k-\sum_{j=k+1}^{M_i}{j \choose k}R_j$. [Inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) gives us that $R_k=T\times P\:(m,n,i,k)$.

---

If we now consider the case of the $n$ numbers not necessarily being distinct (selection **with replacement**), then, if we include $0$ in the set of numbers that may be selected (so that the first gap can be $0$ like the others), we have:

$$
\textrm{P}(A_i=k)\ =\ P\:(m+n,n,i+1,k)
$$

where $P\:$ is as above.

This follows simply from the fact that selecting $n$ numbers from $m+1$ *with* replacement is equivalent to selecting $n$ numbers from $m+n$ *without* replacement, but with each gap being smaller in size by $1$.

Comment: @fanzhang: I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a partial solution  when sampling without replacement:

In addition to the gaps $G_1=a_1$and $G_j:=a_j-a_{j-1}$ for $2\leq j\leq n$, 
it is convenient to introduce the final gap $G_{n+1}=(m+1)-a_n$.

Then the random vector $(G_1,G_2,\dots, G_{n+1})$ gives a random composition
of the number $m+1$. That is, all outcomes $(g_1,g_2,\dots, g_{n+1})$
 with $$g_1+g_2+\cdots+g_{n+1}=m+1,\quad g_j\geq 1$$
are equally likely. There are $m\choose n$ such compositions, as 
found using [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Let's focus on the number $N$ of gaps of size 1. How many compositions of
$m+1$ into $n+1$  parts have exactly $k$ ones? The answer is 
$${n+1\choose k}\,{m-(n+1)\choose n-k}.$$
The left hand binomial coefficient counts how many ways 
we can place the ones, and the right hand binomial coefficient counts
the number of compositions of $m+1-k$ into $n+1-k$ parts where 
all the values are $\geq 2$, via another stars and bars argument. 
Thus $$\mathbb{P}(N=k)={{n+1\choose k}\,{m-(n+1)\choose n-k}\over{m\choose n}}.$$

I haven't thought about larger gaps, but maybe this idea will 
be useful there as well.

Comment: Since order counts, I believe these are called compositions rather than partitions.

Comment: OK, I'll change that.